how to do angular.dev animation?
I want to imitate the angular.dev page animation.
I'm coding an example to imitate the zoom effect to the angular logo, when I scroll the logo gets zoom in. But I want to know how I can do that effect.
If you see this page I'll know what I'm talking about https://angular.dev/

The Angular.dev animation were done using GSAP, it is free for personnal use so you can try it.
You can find more information about any website or web app using Wappalyser
